# `use ';' to separate expressions on the same line` when creating IntArray

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to create an `IntArray` that's defined inline as a constructor argument, like so:

```kotlin
 adapter = SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.activity_dashboard,
     listOf<String>("judul","Keterangan","Gambar").toTypedArray(), IntArray(){R.id.txtJudul,(R.id.txt_keterangan),(R.id.img)}
 )
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
use ';' to sparate expressions on the same line
```

The problem is at the first comma in `IntArray(){R.id.txtJudul,(R.id.txt_keterangan),(R.id.img)}`

How do I create an IntArray inline without getting this error?

Comment: Use [intArrayOf](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/int-array-of.html) `intArrayOf(R.id.txtJudul, R.id.txt_keterangan, R.id.img)`

Comment: @Ani Comments are not to be used to offer resolving advice -- that is what answers are for.  If you didn't want to write an answer because you felt this question was a duplicate, please find a duplicate to close with instead of commenting a solution.  Answers posted as comments can lead to question abandonment -- which is not a good thing for volunteers who actually post answers and then are not dignified by a green tick.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230676/352329

Answer (score 5):

The [constructor for `IntArray`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int-array/-init-.html) doesn't work like that - it takes a length and an initializer function that takes an index and returns the value at that index.  That's overly complicated for this, though.

For creating an `IntArray` in-line with your code, simply use the [`intArrayOf` top-level function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/int-array-of.html) (you can also remove the extra parentheses from your code) in place of `IntArray(){ ... }`:

```kotlin
intArrayOf(R.id.txtJudul, R.id.txt_keterangan, R.id.img)
```